# How to split string with multiple separator?

Tags: c#, split, substring

Let's say that I have a string that has the following:

```
string mystr = "*myid*-myemail-:mypwd:*myid2*-myemail2-:mypwd2:*myid3*-myemail3-:mypwd3:";
```

and I want to get each of the substrings that have the'*' and then add them to a new string and then get each of the values that have the ':' same with the one that has '-', and so I tried this using the split method, but it does not work.

```
string mystr = "*myid*-myemail-:mypwd:*myid2*-myemail2-:mypwd2:*myid3*-myemail3-:mypwd3:";

string[] myid = mystr.Split('*');
string[] myemail = mystr.Split('-');
string[] mypwd = mystr.Split(':');
string ids = "";
string emails = "";
string pwds = "";

 foreach (string k in myid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("THESE ARE THE IDS");
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
foreach (string k in myemail)
{
    Console.WriteLine("THESE ARE THE EMAILS");
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
foreach (string k in mypwd)
{
    Console.WriteLine("THESE ARE THE PASSWORDS");
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
THESE ARE THE IDS

THESE ARE THE IDS
myid
THESE ARE THE IDS
-myemail-:mypwd:
THESE ARE THE IDS
myid2
THESE ARE THE IDS
-myemail2-:mypwd2:
THESE ARE THE IDS
myid3
THESE ARE THE IDS
-myemail3-:mypwd3:
THESE ARE THE EMAILS
*myid*
THESE ARE THE EMAILS
myemail
THESE ARE THE EMAILS
:mypwd:*myid2*
THESE ARE THE EMAILS
myemail2
THESE ARE THE EMAILS
:mypwd2:*myid3*
THESE ARE THE EMAILS
myemail3
THESE ARE THE EMAILS
:mypwd3:
THESE ARE THE PASSWORDS
*myid*-myemail-
THESE ARE THE PASSWORDS
mypwd
THESE ARE THE PASSWORDS
*myid2*-myemail2-
THESE ARE THE PASSWORDS
mypwd2
THESE ARE THE PASSWORDS
*myid3*-myemail3-
THESE ARE THE PASSWORDS
mypwd3
THESE ARE THE PASSWORDS
```

And this is what I want it to look like:

```
THESE ARE THE PASSWORDS
mypwd
mypwd2
mypwd3

 THESE ARE THE EMAILs
myemail
myemail2
myemail3

THESE ARE THE IDS
myid
myid2
myid3
```

Comment: `but it does not work` How _specifically_ does it not work?

Comment: well this is the output of the console                                                      myid
-myemail-:mypwd:
myid2
-myemail2-:mypwd2:
myid3
-myemail3-:mypwd3:
*myid*
myemail
:mypwd:*myid2*
myemail2
:mypwd2:*myid3*
myemail3
:mypwd3:
*myid*-myemail-
mypwd
*myid2*-myemail2-
mypwd2
*myid3*-myemail3-
mypwd3

Comment: Put the output in the question you are setting **and the output you want instead**.

Comment: I assume that your `mystr` actually contains real email addresses & passwords?

Comment: I'd look into [Regex.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @cipher_449449 - And you can't be sure that an email or a password won't have the characters you're trying to split on. You can't use split then. You probably even can't use Regex. What's the source of this string?

Comment: @cipher_449449 - Can you post an actual example of a real string?

Comment: @cipher_449449 - Please note that the real-world data would significantly alter how to answer this question. You should be very clear on what characters can appear in your email and/or passwords.

Comment: I'm aware of that thanks I might be looking for another method of doing this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) for this:

```
string mystr = "*myid*-myemail-:mypwd:*myid2*-myemail2-:mypwd2:*myid3*-myemail3-:mypwd3:";
var matches = Regex.Matches(mystr, @"\*(?<Id>[^*]+)\*-(?<Email>[^-]+)-:(?<Password>[^:]+):");
```

Then, you can either access the matches as follows:

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id=" + match.Groups["Id"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Email=" + match.Groups["Email"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Password=" + match.Groups["Password"].Value);
}
```

Or if you want to group the Ids, emails, and passwords together, use:

```
var ids = matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["Id"].Value);
var emails = matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["Email"].Value);
var passwords = matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["Password"].Value);

foreach (string id in ids)
    Console.WriteLine(id);

foreach (string email in emails)
    Console.WriteLine(email);

foreach (string password in passwords)
    Console.WriteLine(password);
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/LZETX54731)**.

Note, however, that this might break because an email address could contain a hyphen character and the password could contain a colon. In that case, you need to come up with a more robust format for the input text.

Comment: It's fair that this works with the OP's anaemic example string, but it fails quickly with real-world data where the email and/or password contain the splitting characters.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yep, I was just adding that as a warning in the answer :)